# SQL Server case expresssion for text into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, case

Another `Case` expression question, I'm using SQL Server 2016.

I'm trying to return 1 row for each property with multiple customer columns.
Where the property has 1 customer then the 2nd and 3rd customer columns should be null. I've used a join of the same table to return the customer with a `RANK` against the property but my result returns multiple rows for each property.

Desired output:

```
Prop    Cust1   Cust2   Cust3
-------------------------------
PropA   Fred    John    NULL
PropB   Ang     Jo      Allan
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    x.Property as Prop,
    CASE WHEN x.RANK = 1 THEN x.Customer END AS Cust1,
    CASE WHEN x.RANK = 2 THEN x.Customer END AS Cust2,
    CASE WHEN x.RANK = 3 THEN x.Customer END AS Cust3
FROM 
    tbl_CustbyProperty c
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT  
         Cust_ID, Customer, Property
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Property ORDER BY c.customer) AS RANK
     FROM 
         tbl_CustbyProperty) x ON c.Cust_ID = x.Cust_ID
ORDER BY 
    y x.Property
```

Current output:

```
Prop     Cust1   Cust2   Cust3
--------------------------------
PropA    Fred    NULL    NULL
PropA    NULL    John    NULL
PropB    Ang     NULL    NULL
PropB    NULL    Jo      NULL
PropB    NULL    NULL    Allan
```

Comment: show some sample data please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go from your current result to the desired result you could `GROUP BY x.property` and get the `max()` of the `CASE`s. Something similar to:

```
SELECT x.property prop,
       max(CASE 
             WHEN x.rank = 1 THEN
               x.customer
           END) cust1,
       max(CASE
             WHEN x.rank = 2 THEN
               x.customer
           END) cust2,
       max(CASE
             WHEN x.rank = 3 THEN
               x.customer
           END) cust3
       FROM tbl_custbyproperty c
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                              cust_id,
                              customer,
                              property,
                              row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.property
                                                 ORDER BY c.customer) rank
                              FROM tbl_custbyproperty) x
                      ON c.cust_id = x.cust_id
       GROUP BY x.property
       ORDER BY x.property;
```

But probably there is an overall better solution, to your problem as a whole, which you might get, if you edit your question and post the table's `CREATE` statement along with `INSERT` statements for the sample data you got the result with.

Comment: Thanks Sticky, the Max and Group was the trick. There probably is a better mouse trap but happy with this for now